# Stepping Backwards Through a String to Insert a Character

Tags: notepad++

Based on the examples below, using notepad++, how can I insert a comma after the last backslash? Since the number of backslashes can vary, I was thinking that I need to work from the end of the line versus the beginning.

,k:\records\drawings\Plants\Empire\,2001-EXPANSION\SCHEDULES.pdf

,k:\records\drawings\Plants\Empire\,2002-SITE UPDATE\C4.pdf

,k:\records\drawings\Plants\Empire\,2007-HVAC UPDATE\SECTIONS.pdf

,k:\records\drawings\Interceptors\,1932-1-SP-210\PRELIMINARY.pdf

Thanks in Advance,

Nick

Comment: Not an answer but I would write an actual script in an actual scripting language to do this. Ideally you'd parse the CSV properly.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\\\K`
- Replace with: `,`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : beginning of line
  .+    : 1 or more any character
  \\    : backslash
  \K    : forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Result for given example:**

```
,k:\records\drawings\Plants\Empire\,2001-EXPANSION\,SCHEDULES.pdf
,k:\records\drawings\Plants\Empire\,2002-SITE UPDATE\,C4.pdf
,k:\records\drawings\Plants\Empire\,2007-HVAC UPDATE\,SECTIONS.pdf
,k:\records\drawings\Interceptors\,1932-1-SP-210\,PRELIMINARY.pdf
```